# Recipe Health risk Database ERD structure

Tags: database-design

I have these tables:

First table(Recipe table),

> **Recipe**
>
> recipeid(PK,AI)
>
> recipename
>
> ingredients

Second table(Ingredients table),

> **Ingredients**
>
> ingredientid(PK,AI)
>
> ingredientname
>
> quantity

Then a 3rd one for display,

> **Recipe_ingredients**
>
> recipeid(FK)
>
> ingredientid(FK)
>
> quantity

How do i construct another table and its relation to the ingredient table to determine its nutritional value.

Should i add another column for nutrition on my ingredient table? Or create another table for nutrition which holds the ingredient id as FK.

> **Nutrition**
>
> Ingredientid(FK)

Say i am diabetic so i should avoid recipes with high amounts of sugar. So from ingredients... im confused where to move from there.

Comment: Is your question about the subject matter or about the table design?

Comment: I don't understand your table design. I cannot understand what is the meaning of recipe.ingredients columnd and the ingredients.quantity column. Can you tell me about meaning of these olumns?

Comment: I suggest that you name tables and attributes consistently so it will be either `Recipe` & `Ingredient` or `Recipes` & `Ingredients`. The first option is better.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have some risk information in your `NUTRITION` table.  Perhaps a text column to describe the risk and a threshold quantity column, which might be optional, to describe what is a safe and an unsafe amount.

The thing you have to decide is whether you want to try to normalize out some other information from your nutrition risk descriptions.  For example, do you want to have a `MEDICAL_CONDITION` table that allows risks to be categorized in terms of what type of person is at risk (e.g. diabetes, nut allergy, lactose intolerance,...)

From a design perspective, we can't answer your question about what is needed.  That depends on your business rules and what you want to achieve.  We can help with technical design questions based on specific statements of your business rules.

Comment: Would you care to show me the structure of the tables you mentioned? both nutrition and its relation to medical_condition. I think ive grasped what you are trying to convey, but i find it hard to decide the structure of my table. Im referring to the table columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but few notes:

In your proposed Nutrition table the class schema would look like this:

[image: Your version]

It would mean "**Nutrition utilizes Ingredient**" or "**Nutrition *HAS* Ingredient**".
Which I believe is not what you need.

[image: Link to nutrition table]

Instead you need a relation "**Ingredient has Nutrition**", so that  `Nutrition` is an attribute or a property of `Ingredient`. If you need reusable nutrition categories, like "Nutrition level A" etc., you may introduce a separate `Nutrition` table. Then you will have to add `NutritionId` foreign key to the `Ingredient` table.

[image]

Otherwise it is just enough to add a `NutritionValue` attribute to the table `Ingredient`.